# List folder files recursive to file, match columns

Tags: shell-script

Files can be listed recursive like this

```
ls public_html -R -go * | sed 's/[ ]/,/g' > files.csv
```

Problem is that columns won't match. If I open the file in Excel, some dates are in column D and some in E. 
Is there any way to get recursive list and keep columns in place?

Comment: That also won't work with files that have spaces in their names. Filenames with accented characters will additionally be displayed as `?` in some locales, giving you a list of filenames that don't actually exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse `ls`: its output is meant for humans to parse, not machines. You want the `stat` command, and your shell's recursive globbing syntax. Try this:

```
stat -c '%A,%h,%s,%y,%n' public_html/** > file.csv
```

The mtime format will be different. Read the `stat` man page.

Or `find`

```
find public_html -printf "%M,%n,%s,%t,%p\n" > file.csv
```

Comment: For further reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs